# WPF Mouse Events Bug?

Tags: c#, wpf

I found a workaround for this bug I want to understand **why** this is happening. Is it bug? Is there a better workaround? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the plainest code that I could come up with to show the problem. Inside MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <local:AnnoyingBlock Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Tweedle Dee" MouseDown="MoveWindow"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Inside MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MoveWindow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) Dispatcher.Invoke(DragMove);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

class AnnoyingBlock : TextBlock
{
    public AnnoyingBlock()
    {
        MouseLeftButtonUp += OnMouseUp;
        Text = "Tweedle Dumb";
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Boom");
    }
}
```

Run that code and click/drag the text Tweedle Dee. It works as expected and the window is moved with the mouse. Click on the text Tweedle Dumb. The message box shows up.

Now, from the AnnoyingBlock declaration in the xaml, remove the margin and run it again. Run it again and you should see that clicking anywhere in the Tweedle Dee text pops up the message box when you release the mouse. Remove the MouseDown event from the TextBlock in the xaml and run it again. The MouseUp event on the sibling control is no longer fired.

Why does an event on a sibling control get fired? Why does this only happen when you have an event on the control (even though it's a different event MouseDown vs MouseUp)? Why does adding a margin stop this from happening?